# How to convert a python looping program into a mathematical function

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

So i have been working on financial maths and i am interested in finding the end year balance at this year. I wasn't able to find a mathematical way of putting that into a function but i managed to do it through coding. 
And the codes are:

```
x = 1 
zen = int(x)
sumy = 0 
while zen <= 45    
  sumy = 1.035*(5890*pow(1.015,zen-1)+5200+sumy)
  print(sumy)
  zen=zen+1
```

How do i put it in f(x)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the python code calculates an
equivalent function

\begin{align}
s_{m,n}&=
\left(
\frac{b\,c^{m-1}}{a-c}+\frac d{a-1}
\right)\cdot a^{n-m+2}
-\frac{a\,b}{a-c}\cdot c^n
-\frac{a\,d}{a-1}
.
\end{align}

Here is the modifies code, equivalent function and examples:

```
def f(m,n) :
    s = 0 
    k=m
    while k <= n :
      s = a*(b*pow(c,k-1)+d+s)
      k=k+1 
    return s

def g(m,n) :
    return (b*pow(c,m-1)/(a-c)+d/(a-1))*pow(a,n-m+2)-a*b/(a-c)*pow(c,n)-a*d/(a-1)

a=1.035
b=5890
c=1.015
d=5200

print(f(1,45))
print(g(1,45))
# 1406972.3342689278
# 1406972.3342689283
print(f(10,45))
print(g(10,45))
# 983587.628215249
# 983587.6282152492
print(f(16,57))
print(g(16,57))
# 1402491.47280645
# 1402491.4728064497
```

Comment: What do you call this sort of technique? like geometric sequence, series, or what sort of programming.

Comment: @Dev Patel: Yes, mostly sum of geometric sequence
plus solution to recurrence equation
plus a bit of luck, I suppose - it is not always possible 
to convert.